# Creating index for a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table `Person` with two columns `Name` and `Gender` and suppose in my application if I have a query which is called frequently :

```
select * from Person where Gender = 'M'
```

So is it advisable to create an index on the column `Gender`?

Comment: It's almost always advisable to create index. Example where it's not necessary in my opinion would be event log database, where you almost always just write and read rarely. And even when you read, indexing doesn't play any role.

Comment: No. For a column with low cardinailty like Gender (only two or three possible values) the index is unlikely to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not advisable unless there is loads of one an only a few of the other and your query only looks at the few.  A full table scan would give you a much more efficient result than diving through an index.  In fact, even if you created the index, it's highly unlikely the optimiser would use it.

Comment: can you elaborate a little on the line, "unless there is loads of one an only a few of the other".

Comment: Indexes are only really effective when they select a very small proportion of the table.  An indexed search takes, say 3 I/O then one for the table read.  A table scan does one I/O per block, containing many rows.  So say you've got 1% M and 99% F you'd only get a gain using an index to search M.  For F you'd want a table scan.  Worse still, if you got an index-based plan the first time, you might end up using the the same plan for F from the cache, which would be disastrous. One of the few times constants are better than parameters. /off topic

Answer (score 0):

Below points might give you the idea:

From [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_optop.htm)

> In general, index access paths are more efficient for statements that retrieve a small subset of table rows, whereas full table scans are more efficient when accessing a large portion of a table.
>
> Do not index columns that are modified frequently. UPDATE statements that modify indexed columns and INSERT and DELETE statements that modify indexed tables take longer than if there were no index. Such SQL statements must modify data in indexes as well as data in tables. They also generate additional undo and redo.
>
> When choosing to index a key, consider whether the performance gain for queries is worth the performance loss for INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs and the use of the space required to store the index. You might want to experiment by comparing the processing times of the SQL statements with and without indexes. You can measure processing time with the SQL trace facility.

Comment: Good answer, though "keep the index" would *perhaps* result in maintaining an index that is never used.  That said, it could be used to create a marginally faster COUNT of Ms and Fs if that's all the query did.  On the surface, it doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: I agree with you! Corrected :)